# Cropped images in my gallery but they are stacked on top of each other. How do I get them next to each other instead?

Tags: css, image, html, crop

Here is the code:

```
<div class="crop">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" />
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" />
</div>

.crop{
float:left;
margin:2px;
overflow:hidden; /* this is important */
position:relative; /* this is important too */
width:320px;
height:240px;
}
.crop img{
position:absolute;
top:-0px;
left:-0px;
}
```

I'm guessing I need to add something to my CSS? I know a solution would be to put the images as separate divs like this:

```
<div class="crop">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="crop">
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg" />
</div>
```

But I have next/previous arrows in my gallery so I need the images to be in the same div otherwise the arrows won't work.

Comment: Get rid of the `.crop img` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason they are both appearing in the same place is because they are sharing the same css class, just name them differently with different top/left coordinates.